# Airflow best practices - How to correctly approach a workflow

Tags: airflow

I'm implementing a simple workflow in which I have three different data sources (API, parquet file and PostgreSQL database). The goal is to gather the data from all the different sources and store it in a PostgreSQL warehouse.

The task flow I projected goes like:

Create PostrgreSQL DW >> [Get data from source 1, Get data from source 2, Get data from source 3] >> Insert data into PostrgreSQL DW

In order for this to work, I would have to share the data from the "Get Data" tasks to the "Insert Data" task.

My questions are:
Is sharing data between tasks a bad/wrong thing to do?
Should I approach this any other way?
If I implement a task to get the data from the source and then insert it to another database, wouldn't it not be idempotent?

Answer (score 1):

Airflow is primarily an orchestrator. Sharing small snippets of data between tasks is encouraged with [XComs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html), but large amounts of data are not supported. XComs are stored in the Airflow database which would quickly fill up if you used this pattern often.

Your use case sounds more suited to [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/beam-overview/) which is designed to process data in parallel at scale. It's much more common to use Airflow to schedule your beam pipelines, which do the actual work of ETL.

There is an [Airflow Operator for Apache Beam](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-apache-beam/stable/operators.html). Depending on the size of your data you can process it locally on the Airflow workers with the `DirectRunner`. Or if you need to process large amounts of data you can offload the pipeline execution to a cloud solution like GCP's [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow) using Beam's `DataflowRunner`.

The Airflow + Beam pattern is much more common and a powerful combination when dealing with data. Even if your datasets are small this pattern will let you scale with no further effort required if you need to in the future.